# Did Einstein talk about creating a new theory being like climbing a mountain?

Tags: quotes, albert-einstein

Did Einstein say the following:

> Creating a new theory is not like destroying an old barn and erecting a skyscraper in its place. It is rather like climbing a mountain, gaining new and wider views, discovering unexpected connections between our starting points and its rich environment. But the point from which we started out still exists and can be seen, although it appears smaller and forms a tiny part of our broad view gained by the mastery of the obstacles on our adventurous way up.

It is attributed to him in many places, but I cannot find the original source.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Evolution_of_Physics) points towards [this download page](https://archive.org/details/evolutionofphysi033254mbp). And indeed we find:
[image]

I think this is not from the very first printing/edition. So, if one wants to be 100% certain (about the time), one would have to look up the very first edition as well: *The Evolution of Physics*, Albert Einstein & Leopold Infeld, 1938, Edited by C.P. Snow, Cambridge University Press, ASIN: B000S52QZ4.

It appears that your quote is not 100% accurate. Also, I suggest that the attribution should be to the *duo* Einstein and Infeld.